# can't connect to mongodb through url in ubuntu18.04

Tags: django, mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to connect mongodb with my django application. Help me with this situation.

This is for Ubuntu-18.04 users running mongodb. I tried to run mongodb through command mongo and it worked where i created a db and user but when i use command mongod, it seemed good but when i entered localhost:27017 in firefox i get the error "The connection was reset" and it showed this error in terminal. I don't know what to do.

```
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2737 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=django
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.3
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2019-08-02T13:50:45.825+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2019-08-02T13:50:45.826+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=987M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-08-02T13:50:46.642+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1564734046:642926][2737:0x7efe8d2d10c0], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 6/18304
2019-08-02T13:50:46.729+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1564734046:729932][2737:0x7efe8d2d10c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 6 through 7
2019-08-02T13:50:46.788+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1564734046:788289][2737:0x7efe8d2d10c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 7 through 7
2019-08-02T13:50:46.866+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-08-02T13:50:46.866+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-08-02T13:50:46.866+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-08-02T13:50:46.866+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-08-02T13:50:46.867+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2019-08-02T13:50:46.867+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
2019-08-02T13:50:46.867+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
2019-08-02T13:50:46.867+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2019-08-02T13:50:46.867+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2019-08-02T13:50:46.867+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2019-08-02T13:50:46.867+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-08-02T13:50:46.909+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2019-08-02T13:50:46.909+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

This was ok but after loading loaclhost:27017 in firefox it additionally shows this below in terminal

```
2019-08-02T13:51:43.449+0530 I NETWORK  [conn1] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSLHandshakeFailed. Ending connection from 127.0.0.1:47792 (connection id: 1)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.449+0530 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:47792 (0 connections now open)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.450+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47794 #2 (1 connection now open)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.450+0530 I NETWORK  [conn2] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSLHandshakeFailed. Ending connection from 127.0.0.1:47794 (connection id: 2)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.450+0530 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:47794 (0 connections now open)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.450+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47796 #3 (1 connection now open)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.450+0530 I NETWORK  [conn3] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSLHandshakeFailed. Ending connection from 127.0.0.1:47796 (connection id: 3)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.450+0530 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:47796 (0 connections now open)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.450+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47798 #4 (1 connection now open)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.451+0530 I NETWORK  [conn4] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSLHandshakeFailed. Ending connection from 127.0.0.1:47798 (connection id: 4)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.451+0530 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:47798 (0 connections now open)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.451+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47800 #5 (1 connection now open)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.451+0530 I NETWORK  [conn5] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSLHandshakeFailed. Ending connection from 127.0.0.1:47800 (connection id: 5)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.451+0530 I NETWORK  [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:47800 (0 connections now open)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.451+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:47802 #6 (1 connection now open)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.451+0530 I NETWORK  [conn6] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSLHandshakeFailed. Ending connection from 127.0.0.1:47802 (connection id: 6)
2019-08-02T13:51:43.452+0530 I NETWORK  [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:47802 (0 connections now open)
```

connections are accepted first and then ending by opening in another port. Clearly I can't understand, what to do now?

Comment: It looks like your MongoDB is expecting SSL connections and you're connecting insecurely.

Comment: what should i do for a secure connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the mongodb server in TGZ format from the link https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community and extracted in the `/usr/local/bib` folder manually. Then I ran the command `mongod` in the terminal and entered `localhost:27017` in the browser then i recieved this response ***It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.***
This is what I have been looking for.